# Undefined property: stdclass but property does exist?

Tags: php, variables, object

When I run my script, I get the following error message:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$sub in /path/to/cron_monitor.php on line 14
```

Line 14 is this (included line 13, since it's relevant as well):

```
$data=(object)$obj;
$subject=$data->sub;
```

Google/Other stack questions tells me that the property shouldn't exist, but if I do `var_dump($data)`, I get this (excerpt from larger portion, but `$data` is output from the 4chan `catalog.json` API), which indicates that it does exist:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (26) {
  ["no"]=>
  int(176833602)
  ["now"]=>
  string(21) "05/15/17(Mon)02:08:45"
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "Anonymous"
  ["sub"]=>
  string(28) "/dfg/ Dwarf Fortress General"
  ["com"]=>
  string(2173) "(excluded since it just bloats up the question, the string is correct)"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(12) "Human Farmer"
  ["ext"]=>
  string(4) ".jpg"
  ["w"]=>
  int(1530)
  ["h"]=>
  int(1027)
  ["tn_w"]=>
  int(250)
  ["tn_h"]=>
  int(167)
  ["tim"]=>
  float(1494828525011)
  ["time"]=>
  int(1494828525)
  ["md5"]=>
  string(24) "0tPuwatHh8Kq/xHEEaWR2Q=="
  ["fsize"]=>
  int(1205673)
  ["resto"]=>
  int(0)
  ["bumplimit"]=>
  int(0)
  ["imagelimit"]=>
  int(0)
  ["semantic_url"]=>
  string(26) "dfg-dwarf-fortress-general"
  ["custom_spoiler"]=>
  int(1)
  ["replies"]=>
  int(435)
  ["images"]=>
  int(113)
  ["omitted_posts"]=>
  int(432)
  ["omitted_images"]=>
  int(110)
  ["last_replies"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["no"]=>
      int(176969172)
      ["now"]=>
      string(21) "05/16/17(Tue)13:14:50"
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "Anonymous"
      ["com"]=>
      string(171) "(excluded since it just bloats up the question, the string is correct)"
      ["time"]=>
      int(1494954890)
      ["resto"]=>
      int(176833602)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["no"]=>
      int(176969476)
      ["now"]=>
      string(21) "05/16/17(Tue)13:18:23"
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "Anonymous"
      ["com"]=>
      string(124) "(excluded since it just bloats up the question, the string is correct)"
      ["time"]=>
      int(1494955103)
      ["resto"]=>
      int(176833602)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(6) {
      ["no"]=>
      int(176969731)
      ["now"]=>
      string(21) "05/16/17(Tue)13:21:20"
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "Anonymous"
      ["com"]=>
      string(179) "(excluded since it just bloats up the question, the string is correct)"
      ["time"]=>
      int(1494955280)
      ["resto"]=>
      int(176833602)
    }
  }
  ["last_modified"]=>
  int(1494955280)
}
```

Oddly enough, I also have a line later

```
$threadno=$data->no;
```

And that does return valid values (integers).

EDIT: My entire codeblock:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include "chan_archiver.php";
include "config.php";

class threadMonitor extends chan_archiver{
        function monitorCatalog($boardwatch, $filter, $basedescription) {
                $json=json_decode( file_get_contents('http://a.4cdn.org/'.$boardwatch.'/catalog.json'),true);
                $monitordescription=$basedescription.date(DATE_RFC850);
                foreach( $json as $thread ){
                        $arr=$thread['threads'];
                        foreach( $arr as $obj ){
                                $data=(object)$obj;
                                var_dump($data);
                                $subject=$data->sub;
                                if (strpos($subject, $filter) !== false){
                                                $threadno=$data->no;
                                                $this->addThread($threadno, $boardwatch, $monitordescription);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
$t=new threadMonitor();

/* IMPORTANT: Add arguments like this:
  board filter basedescription
  Example crontab command (that last space is needed, the command automatically adds the added date and time to the thread):
        php /path/to/cron_monitor.php vg "/dfg/" "Dwarf Fortress General - "
*/

$t->monitorCatalog($argv[1],$argv[2],$argv[3]);
?>
```

Comment: So what is `$obj` before you feel the need to try and cast it to an object

Comment: That `var_dump()` also looks a little odd as there are no property visibility mentioned like `public/protected/private` on the properties?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I've attached my codeblock to the post. Maybe I'm doing something utterly wrong. It's the first time I'm seriously trying to do anything with PHP, so something may be entirely wrong somewhere else that causes this.

Comment: Can you also supply a sample of the raw json string as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly - http://a.4cdn.org/vg/catalog.json is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not going quite deep enough into your data structure

And it looks like `sub` does not always exist in all the occurances, which may be why you are getting an error

```
foreach( $json as $obj ){

    foreach ( $obj->threads as $thread ) {
        echo $thread->no . PHP_EOL;
        echo $thread->now . PHP_EOL;
        if ( isset($thread->sub) ) {
            echo $thread->sub . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Worked, but I had to define both `$obj` and `$thread` as being objects, otherwise I got errors. Thanks a bunch for helping me out.

Comment: Thats strange. I used your JSONString and I did not need to